# Composition of faithfully flat ring extensions

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, modules, flatness, projective-modules

Let $R$ be a not necessarily commutative, unital, ring, and for simplicity let module always mean right module. We say that a unital ring extension $R \hookrightarrow S$ is *flat*, or *faithfully flat*, if $S$ is flat, or respectively faithfully flat, as an $R$-module.

Is the composition of two flat, faithfully flat, ring extensions again flat, respectively faithfully flat?

Edit: It seems that in the commutative case this is true. See

https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00H9

for a proof. Does the argument extend to the noncommutative setting?

Comment: Well if the proof extends to the non-commutative case (and I agree that it does) it must be true... What is your question again?

Comment: I guess my question is if the commutative proof extends to the noncommutative setting.

Comment: You didn't write that ;-) Anyway: It clearly does. Of course, you have to make sure to carefully distinguish between "$S$ is (faithfully) flat as a left-$R$-module" and "$S$ is faithfully flat as a right-$R$-module", but the proof goes through if $M'$ and $S$ are both considered as right-modules.